# inertial frame quaternions vs Body frame quaternions

Tags: quaternions

I have searched a lot everywhere, leading to more confusion, what is the difference between inertial frame quaternions vs Body frame quaternions, what DCM they represent and how to update both using gyro angular rates? Is this has something to do with quaternion left multiplication vs quaternion right multiplication..?

Answer (score 0):

Difference that one represent transformation (of the 3d point) FROM body frame TO inertial frame and other FROM inertial frame TO body frame. 
And B_I = I_B^-1